# FragmentPagerAdapter vs FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In my application i once opening a new dialog within my Fragments. I was using a FrgmentPagerAdapter. Whenever i opened a new activity from within my code, i got a null pointer exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
```

After alot of search i came to the conclusion that i should use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and not a `FragmentAdapter`. Now this has solved my problem for the null pointer exception. When using the Fragment Adapter i had written code in the

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
                   //
        }
    }
```

to know when the Fragment becomes visible to the user. How this function is not getting called. What am i doing wrong ? Can anyone point me to the solution of the NULL pointer exception using Fragment Pager or the `setUserVisibleHint` not been called with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter ?

Answer (score 0):

FragmentStatePagerAdapter had a bug in it where it was not calling setUserVisibleHint properly.  It was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/bf7974e46b008ffa4a16c61386735c4817d343aa

Make sure you're using revision 11 or higher of the Android Support Library at http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

> Android Support Library, revision 11 (November 2012)
>
> Changes for v4 support library:
>
> Fixed issue with user-visible hint in FragmentStatePagerAdapter.